# polymer elements don't seem to accept styles within a template

Tags: javascript, web, polymer, paper-elements

I'm using a polymer core-icon within my custom element and attempting to style it by it's element name.  The button in my example shows up with a blue background, why doesn't the core-icon appear larger(200X200px)?  I'm I misunderstanding something?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-icons/core-icons.html">
    <polymer-element name="test-one" noscript>
        <template>
            <style>
                core-icon {
                    width: 200px;
                    height: 200px;
                }
                button {
                    background-color: blue;
                }
            </style>
            <h1><core-icon icon="android"></core-icon>howdy! </h1>
            <button>I'm a button</button>
        </template>
    </polymer-element>
</head>
<body>
    <test-one>transclude me!</test-one>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `core-icon[icon="android"]`. I believe the styling neesds higher specificity than the just the tag.

Comment: It looks like that works, thanks.   Also, I noticed setting the background color did flow through to the icon.  Using !important on the width and height properties forced them to work, so I guess the default 24px size for icons might be clobbering my width and height. values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the html /deep/ core-icon style doesn't get overridden by a tag style, and you need to use either the icon attribute give the core-icon an additional id and style it by that.